# Including different libraries for different bin_Programs in autotool

Tags: c++, makefile, build, autotools, autoconf

We are building our c++ applications with Autotools. We are creating two bin_Programs in Makefile.am as below:

`bin_PROGRAMS = \
    applications/A/a \
    applications/B/b`

Currently, we are including the same libraries to both of these programs as below:

`INCLUDES = -I@NE_ROOT@ -I@CORE_ROOT@/include @MYLIB_CFLAGS@ @BOOST_CFLAGS@ @LOG4CPP_CFLAGS@`

This is the definition of `@MYLIB_CFLAGS@`:

```
MYLIB_CFLAGS=-I${mylib_include_dir}
```

The variables in Makefile.am are empty as below:

```
applications_A_a_SOURCES = 

applications_A_a_LDADD =

applications_A_a_LDFLAGS =
```

and we are defining the same variables for b program.

I have noticed that the b program doesn't need `@MYLIB_CFLAGS@`in the includes and while trying to update Glibc this is causing problems. My question is if there is a way to include `@MYLIB_CFLAGS@` for "a" application but not for "b" application.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Currently, we are including the same libraries to both of these
>   programs as below:
>
> ```
> INCLUDES = -I@NE_ROOT@ -I@CORE_ROOT@/include @MYLIB_CFLAGS@ @BOOST_CFLAGS@ @LOG4CPP_CFLAGS@
> ```

It is to your advantage to get the terminology straight, as that will make it easier to communicate with others about such issues and to interpret documentation, such as [the Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html).  To that end, the purpose intended to be served by the `INCLUDES` variable is to hold compiler flags that indicate locations that should appear in the search path for C and C++ `#include` directives, or that serve analogous purposes for compilers for other languages.  It is only indirectly about libraries, and when used as intended, it certainly does not *cause* anything to be included anywhere.

Furthermore, and more directly related to your question, that makes the `INCLUDES` variable an adjunct to the various `*_CPPFLAGS` variables that are more generally intended to be used to convey flags intended to modulate the behavior of the preprocessor.  This is is as distinguished from flags intended to modulate the behavior of the compiler proper, for which `*_CFLAGS` (C), `*_CXXFLAGS` (C++), and a few others are designated.  One can often get away with using the wrong variable to convey flags, but it does make a bit of difference.  And of course one is not required to adhere to these naming conventions for project-specific variables, but I prefer to do so to keep things clear.

Thus, considering ...

> This is the definition of @MYLIB_CFLAGS@:
>
> ```
> MYLIB_CFLAGS=-I${mylib_include_dir}
> ```

... the only flag being conveyeed by that variable is an `-I` flag, so if I were doing the naming, that variable would be `MYLIB_CPPFLAGS`.  But this is a project-specific variable, so the significance of its name is whatever you decide it is.

> The variables in Makefile.am are empty as below:

Well that's not very useful, and I suspect that it has in fact misled you.  It's not necessary to specify empty variables to Automake.  Doing so does not have a different meaning to Automake than does omitting the variable altogether, but I suspect it may have given you the impression that those given in your `Makefile.am` are the only per-target variables available.  They are not.  In fact, there are *many* more, as listed [in the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Program-and-Library-Variables).

In particular, there are (notionally) variables `applications_A_a_CPPFLAGS` and `applications_B_b_CPPFLAGS` where you would list preprocessor flags that are specific to one target or the other.  These are cumulative with global-effect variables such as `INCLUDES`, so one way you could solve the problem described would be to change `INCLUDES` and add `applications_A_a_CPPFLAGS`, like so:

```
INCLUDES = -I@NE_ROOT@ -I@CORE_ROOT@/include @BOOST_CFLAGS@ @LOG4CPP_CFLAGS@

applications_A_a_CPPFLAGS = @MYLIB_CFLAGS@
```

Now the flags in `@MYLIB_CFLAGS@` will be used only in building `applications_A_a`.

I note also that it is suspicious that you say *all* the target-specific variables listed in the `Makefile.am` file are empty.  That's not necessarily wrong, but do note libraries that are not header-only will need to be represented in the linker variables somehow, too.  Perhaps you have an `LDADD` variable by which the same libraries are designated for all targets (or perhaps you do it with `AM_LDFLAGS`, which might work under some circumstances but would be incorrect, or perhaps you use `LDFLAGS`, which would be worse).  If you need to do it then the correct way to designate binary libraries that are specific to one program target or the other would be via variables `applications_A_a_LDADD` and `applications_B_b_LDADD`.

Comment: Thank you I got my answer. You are right about LDADD, I missed that some libraries are added to one of applications LDADD, but not mylib. Actually Mylib is a shared object with two header files. I am not seeing anywhere that we are adding .so file to the LDADD but while updating GLibc during make, I  am getting a warning that STDC++ used  in cross compiler is conflicting with stdc++ used for mylib.so. Because of this I thought that include is including the library.